# javascript function containing ajax do not work after submit but work with button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

it is strange. I have a function with ajax that works great:

```
function searchProduct(){
var barcode=$.trim($('#barcode1').val());
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://.............',
        data:{ 
            action: "search", 
            var: barcode, 
            },
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(output){
```

when I call this function from a form submit event, any way, I get error function of ajax.

```
<form id="searchBox" name="searchBox" onsubmit="searchProduct()">
```

BUT if I call this function with button click event its works and get success()

```
<span  class="tab-label" onclick="searchProduct()">Scan</span>
```

what you think about this?

Comment: Which error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form submit will actually send a HttpRequest to the web server, I wonder why do you want to send an AJAX request along with that.

OnClick will be simple event you can use it to trigger AJAX request, it will not send any other HttpRequest to the server.

Answer (score 2):

On form **submit** event you have to stop its default behavior using `preventDefault()` otherwise post back will occur and that could be reason of error.

Pass current element reference to the function using `searchProduct(this)` and in the function use `preventDefault()` like this:

```
<form id="searchBox" name="searchBox" onsubmit="searchProduct(this);">
```

**Jquery:**

```
function searchProduct(event){
var barcode=$.trim($('#barcode1').val());
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://.............',
        data:{ 
            action: "search", 
            var: barcode, 
            },
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(output){
         }
      });

     event.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: don't forget to mark it answer if problem solved..:)